# Remove all words that appear fewer than 5 times in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a text file that has a string on each line, like:

```
zanzibar
apple
banana
apple
carrot
banana
sausage
apple
apricot
tea
apple
apple
```

I'm trying to read the file, count each word, and remove the words have a count of less than 5. Words which appear more than 5 times get left with only one occurrence.

For the above, the new file should have

```
apple
```

because it appears more than 5 times in the file.

What I tried so far is the first step -> to remove the strings that appear fewer than 5 times but even this doesn't seem to work. The new file stays empty.

```
awk -F'\n' '
  FNR==NR{ seen[tolower($1)]++; next }
  seen[tolower($1)]
  seen[tolower($1)]<5{ delete seen[tolower($1)] }
' all.txt 5-or-more.txt
```

UPDATE:

I'm running the following:

```
awk '{ a[tolower($1)]++ } 
    END{
        for(word in a){ 
            if(a[word]>5){ print word }
        }
    }' all.txt > sorted.txt
```

Comment: Why do you have two input files? What is `all.txt`? Do you already have the list of words you want?

Comment: @terdon, I have only the sorted text file (alphabetically). I thought the second file will be used to store the new values

Comment: Oh. No, you would need `> 5-or-more.txt` for that

Comment: (1) A nit-pick: You say what you want done with words with a count of less than 5 and what you want done with words that appear more than 5 times.  What do you want done with words that appear exactly five times?  (My point is that the opposite of “less than 5” (“< 5”) is “*five **or more***” (“≥ 5” in mathematical notation, “`>= 5`” in code).)  (I see now that one of the answerers made this same comment, but you still haven’t edited your question to fix it.) … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) If you wanted what you say you want, you would want an output file that says `apple` `apple` `apple` `apple` `apple`.  The output that you show would be described as “list the words that appear five or more times”.  The “leave it just once” phrase is unclear and easily overlooked.  (3) If you want the test for equality to be done in a case-insensitive way, you should *say so,* and maybe include `Apple` and `appLe` in the example input file.  Showing us that you used `tolower()` in your attempts isn’t enough to make it clear what processing you want. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) The code at the end of your question looks like it should work (aside from outputting the words in an unspecified order). What happens when you run it? Does it give you satisfactory output? If it does, you shouldn’t put it into the question; just accept the answer you copied it from. (Although I notice that you accepted a *different* answer.) If it doesn’t, you should say what result you get and why it is unsatisfactory.  (5) Your question should say what order you want the output in, if there are multiple words that appear five or more times. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Ideally, you would (*also*) show this in the example input/output.  (6) If you want to expand your requirements to include an occurrence *count* in the output, you should [edit] that into the question, and not just mention it in a comment under an answer.  (But actually, you shouldn’t make changes like that to a question after it has received answers.  Rather, [ask a new question](/questions/ask).)  (7) I hate to be harsh, but it would be great if you would learn the fundamentals of how to modify files and create new files before you ask how to do text processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a two-pass into the file approach:

```bash
awk '
  {word = tolower($0)}
  !second_pass {n[word]++; next}
  n[word] >= 5 {delete n[word]; print}' file second_pass=1 file > result
```

That selects the first among 5+ duplicates, preserving the order.

Above, *words* are `$0`, the full contents of the line including whitespace if any (`"word"` is different from `"word "` in that regard). Replace `$0` with `$1` for the first whitespace¹-delimited field of each line. Adding `{$1=$1}` at the top of the `awk` code would also canonify the spacing: remove leading and trailing whitespace¹ and replace all other sequences of one or more whitespace¹ characters with a single space character.

---

<sup>¹ Note that what `awk` regards as *whitespace* varies with the implementation and the locale. That includes at least the *space* and *horizontal tabulation* characters.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'm doing something wrong but when I execute the above awk - the file is still the same. Nothing changed.

Comment: @Gordon, it doesn't change the file, it outputs the result on stdout. Redirect to a file if you want that to be stored somewhere. If you get no output, it's likely that there is different amount of whitespace around the `apple` words. See the note at the end.

Comment: Yes, you're right. When I changed it with `$1` it prints the results on stdout. How should I redirect the output to the file? adding `> another-file` after the last `file`? (yes, that seems to work)

Comment: Is it possible in this solution to include the count of how many times the word appears before deleting it? The output like `COUNT: print`

Comment: @Gordon, that would be a different question, please ask separately, including expected output as I'm not sure what you mean here.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want `-F'\n'`. That would set the field separator to a newline and that will never do anything useful since the record separator is left unchanged and that is also `\n`.

All you need is something like this:

```
$ awk '{ a[tolower($1)]++ } 
    END{
        for(word in a){ 
            if(a[word]>=5){ print word }
        }
    }' file
apple
```

That saves each word (`$1`) as a key in the array `a`, incrementing its value every time the word is seen. Then, at the end of the file, we iterate over `a` and print any word whose value in `a` is greater than or equal to 5.

Comment: For some reason when I try either of the above the file 5-or-more.txt still stays empty.

Comment: @Gordon yes, of course it stays empty. If you want the output of a command to go to a new file, you need `command > outfile`. So here, run `awk '...' all.txt > 5-or-more.txt `.

Comment: I have updated my question about what I'm running and nothing is saved in `sorted.txt`. Where is my mistake here?

Comment: @Gordon your mistake is that your input file doesn't have any word that appears _more than five times_. The word `apple` appears 5 times, not more than five, so it isn't printed. That is what you had asked for, but I guess you actually want "5 or more" instead. so try the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

The task seems ordinary.

```
awk '++A[$0] == 5' file1 >file2
```

Maybe `== 6` It's definitely more than 5 times and prints one time.

Comment: Is it possible in this solution to include the count of how many times the word appears before deleting it? The output in file2, like COUNT | print?

Comment: @Gordon. I added a redirect to the second file and yes it is possible. Check

Comment: @Gordon. `awk '++A[$0] == 5' file1 | tee file2`

Answer (score 2):

This is probably easier to do using `sort` and `uniq -c` to do the counting.

```
$ sort --ignore-case all.txt |
    uniq -c --ignore-case |
    awk '$1 >= 5 {print $2}'
apple
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it but nothing showed up on the console

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `datamash` and `awk`.

```
 $ datamash -i -sW -g 1 count 1 <file | awk '$2 >= 5 {print $1}'
```